# How to handle LaTeX/PDF doc reviews?

Tags: pdf, latex, review

I am a Ph.D student, and I usually write articles which are later proof-read by my supervisor. I usually do it in LaTeX and reviews are done to the PDF outputs in Adobe Reader itself. There are mostly grammatical ones and mostly I miss prepositions and conjuctions in fast writing. To re-phrase everything I have to manually enter everything in my LaTeX script again.

This seems to be hell lot of work and this goes on multiple times sometimes. Is there any software in current world that makes the task easier? For example, if a text stuck out for grammar errors and suggested alternatives, can I accept the changes to replace old one with new phrase or sentence and also able to blank out the striked text. Please suggest me a tool which really makes my life easier.

Comment: With SVN/GIT or some other VCS you can get a diff back from review and merge/reject fragments of it as you see fit.

Comment: _To re-phrase everything i have to manually enter everything in my latex script again_ - I'm not an expert on LaTeX, but don't you just correct the mistakes in the script and regen its output? What do you have to manually enter again?

Comment: see, if a sentence i have written has grammatical mistakes, those were corrected by my supervisor by reviewing the document. Those comments/corections were displayed in my PDF. I want a tool that accept the chnages made by him.

Comment: Ah, right, I understand - interesting question. I don't have any answers, but I hope you find a solution. Perhaps this is a "gap in the market" you can fulfil? `:)`

Comment: I have been struggling with similar type of problem than described here for 3 years now and have not found a good solution. The difference in my case is that my coauthors refuse to use latex and do not know how to edit pdfs. In my discipline everyone uses either MS Word or Open Office. To me it appears that the solution would be to find a robust way to convert LateX documents or pdf outputs to doc/odt format and use track changes feature in Word/Open Office. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a robust conversion tool that would work for Latex templates of journal articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the following link. It has some good information about version controlling.
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Collaborative_Writing_of_LaTeX_Documents

Answer (score 1):

You could attach the LaTeX sources to the PDF (with the `attachfile2` package), so reviewers can directly edit the source and send that back. Or you try to accept comments to the PDF, but currently only Adobe Reader and Foxit allow that - and not on Linux.